# Find $P(7/8)$ given ${P(5)}^2=P(6)$ and $(x-1)P(x+1)=(x+2)P(x)$

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

There's a polynomial $P(x)$, we know that ${P(5)}^2=P(6)$ and $$(x-1)P(x+1)=(x+2)P(x)$$

Find the value of $P(\frac{7}{8})$.

Any hints?

I know that $P(1)=0,P(0)=0,P(-1)=0$ and $P(5)=0$ or $P(5)=\frac{7}{4}$. But what next?

Comment: Can you calculate $P(2)$? $P(3)$? Since $P$ is a polynomial, what you can infer about it?

Comment: If $P(5)=\frac{7}{4}$, then i can calculate $P(2),P(3),P(4)$ etc.

Comment: And since P is a polynomial, we know that it is a continuous function, and it has a form $a(x-a_1)(x-a_2)......$

Comment: If $P(5)=0$ then $P(6)=0$ which implies that $P(7)=0$ which implies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $P\equiv 0$ is a trivial solution of the equation. So, let us assume $P$ is not identically zero. By plugging $x=1$, it follows that $P(1)=0$. Knowing this, we can observe that $P$ also has $0,-1$ as its roots. Define a polynomial $Q$ as
$$
Q(x)=\frac{P(x)}{x(x-1)(x+1)}.
$$ From the given relation, we know that $Q(x)=Q(x+1)$. Note that if $Q$ has a root $x_0$, then it should have infinite number of roots $x_0+k$,  $\ k\in\Bbb Z$, which is absurd since $Q$ is a non-zero polynomial. Thus $Q$ must be a $0$-degree polynomial. This gives $P(x)=cx(x-1)(x+1)$, and from $P(5)^2=P(6)$, we have that
$
(120c)^2=210c,
$ i.e. $c=\frac{7}{480}$. It follows that
$$
P(\frac78)=c\frac 78(-\frac18)\frac{15}8=-\frac{49}{2^{14}}.
$$

Comment: Or $P(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. I appreciate your comment !

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Solving the recurrence equation

$$
(x-1)P(x+1)-(x+2)P(x) = 0
$$

we have

$$
P(x) = C_0(x^3-x)
$$

but $P(5)^2 = P(6)$ or $C_0^2(5^3-5)^2 = C_0(6^3-6)$ giving $C_0$ etc.

Of course $P(x)\equiv 0$ is also a solution.