# Let $P(x)$ be a nonzero polynomial such that $(x-1)P(x+1)=(x+2)P(x)$ for every real $x$, and $P(2)^2=P(3).$ Find the leading coefficient of $P(x)$.

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification

> Question: Let $P(x)$ be a nonzero polynomial such that $(x-1)P(x+1)=(x+2)P(x)$ for every real $x$, and $P(2)^2=P(3).$ Find the leading coefficient of $P(x)$.

Solution: Let $(*)$ represent the identity $$(x-1)P(x+1)=(x+2)P(x), \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$ Substituting $x=1$ in $(*)$ we obtain $P(1)=0$. Again substituting $x=0$ in $(*)$ we have $$-P(1)=2P(0)\implies P(0)=0.$$ Finally substituting $x=-1$ in $(*)$ we have $$-2P(0)=P(-1)\implies P(-1)=0.$$ Thus, we have $P(-1)=P(0)=P(1)=0$.

Now substituting $x=2$ in $(*)$ we have $$P(3)=4P(2)\implies P(2)^2=4P(2)\implies P(2)(P(2)-4)=0\implies P(2)=0 \text{ or }P(2)=4.$$ Note that if $P(2)=0$, then $P(3)=0$. Also note that substituting $x=3,4,5,\dots$ we obtain $P(n)=0, \forall n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge -1}.$ This implies that $P(x)$ is a zero polynomial, which is a contradiction. Thus, $P(2)\neq 0$ and $P(2)=4$. Now since $-1,0$ and $1$ are the roots of $P(x)$, thus we can write $P(x)$ as $$P(x)=(x-1)x(x+1)Q(x)$$ for some $Q(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x].$

Thus for all $x$ we have $$P(x+1)=x(x+1)(x+2)Q(x+1)\\\implies (x-1)P(x+1)=(x-1)x(x+1)(x+2)Q(x+1).$$ Similarly for all $x$ we have $$(x+2)P(x)=(x-1)x(x+1)(x+2)Q(x+1).$$ Thus, by $(*)$, we can conclude that $Q(x)=Q(x+1)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. This implies that for all $x,$ $Q(x)=C,$ where $C\neq 0$ is a constant. Now it is easy to show that $C=\frac{2}{3}.$ Thus, for all $x$ we have $$P(x)=\frac{2}{3}(x-1)x(x+1),$$ that is, the leading coefficient of $P(x)$ is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Is this solution correct and rigorous enough and is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you check if your $P(x)$ is indeed a solution?

Comment: Looks rigorous enough to me. @JCAA, OP has checked the condition in the explicit expressions for $(x-1)P(x+1)=(x+2)P(x)=(x-1)x(x+1)(x+2)Q(x)$, where $Q(x)$ has turned out to be constant.

Comment: It's basically the same solution as in [Find $P(7/8)$ given ${P(5)}^2=P(6)$ and $(x-1)P(x+1)=(x+2)P(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134763/find-p7-8-given-p52-p6-and-x-1px1-x2px). See also https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1886520p12855757.